# How to add extra best selling products to Storefront theme Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

I'm new in woocommerce. How can I extend standart Storefront's best selling section from 4x1 to 4x4, 16 products on main page? When I have tried mannualy change storefront_best_selling_products function, nothing does not work.

Comment: You can also add custom query to get best selling product.

Comment: @Mishra,  my answer is working for you or not?

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in your functions.php:

```
function storefront_best_selling_products( $args ) {

if ( storefront_is_woocommerce_activated() ) {
$args = apply_filters( ‘storefront_best_selling_products_args’, array(
‘limit’   => 5,
‘columns’ => 5,
‘title’      => esc_attr__( ‘Best Sellers’, ‘storefront’ ),
) );
echo ‘<section class=”storefront-product-section storefront-best-selling-products” aria-label=”Best Selling Products”>’;
do_action( ‘storefront_homepage_before_best_selling_products’ );
do_action( ‘storefront_homepage_after_best_selling_products_title’ );
echo storefront_do_shortcode( ‘best_selling_products’, array(
‘per_page’ => intval( $args[‘limit’] ),
‘columns’  => intval( $args[‘columns’] ),
) );
do_action( ‘storefront_homepage_after_best_selling_products’ );
echo ‘</section>’;
}
}
```

Shortcode

```
add_shortcode( ‘best_sellers’, ‘storefront_best_selling_products’ );
```

use  "best_sellers" shortcode like this

```
do_shortcode('[best_sellers]');
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Please can you point me where should I use add_shortcode and do_shortcode?

Comment: In a front-end when you want to display product, you can put in that page.

Answer (score 0):

```
// "Best Sellers" Home products section
add_filter( 'storefront_best_selling_products_args', 'filter_storefront_best_selling_products_args', 10, 1 ); 
function filter_storefront_best_selling_products_args( $args ) {
    $args['orderby'] = 'rand'; // Random
    $args['limit'] = 16; // Quantity in total
    $args['columns'] = 4;

    return $args;
}
```

Paste above code into bottom of child theme's functions.php and change the number of 'limit' and 'columns' accordingly.

Source: [Customize displayed products on Woocommerce Storefront home page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012817/customize-displayed-products-on-woocommerce-storefront-home-page)