# Show subcategories of a main category in "Shop By Category" section in Woocommerce Storefront

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, storefront, taxonomy-terms

I'm setting up a Woocommerce shop using Storefront Theme and I would like know how can I show subcategories instead of categories in the "Shop by Category" homepage section?

I need to show product subcategories instead because my root product category is a unique  one ("Collection"), and within it I have all the main sub-categories.

Comment: Woocommerce Catalog' settings didn't allow you to do that? Any details? May be that was answered here:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/111992/how-can-i-list-only-subcategories-in-woocommerce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can only display the subcategories of one parent category term ID, which is the case for your "Collection" product category:

```
add_filter( 'storefront_product_categories_args', 'custom_storefront_product_categories_args');
function custom_storefront_product_categories_args( $args ) {
    $args['columns'] = 4; // 4 columns
    $args['limit'] = 8;   // 8 items on 2 rows
    $args['child_categories'] = '18'; // <= The term ID of the main parent category

    return $args;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

Storefront home related: [Customize displayed products on Woocommerce Storefront home page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012817/customize-displayed-products-on-woocommerce-storefront-home-page/55013166#55013166)